# Spyder Python IDE (Anaconda) suddenly becomes very slow

Tags: mac, python, anaconda

I use Anaconda Spyder IDE to code in Python. The system is MacOS High Sierra.

It was not super fast before, but since last week, Spyder became extremely slow. It won't return results for simple commands like `data.header()`. It also doesn't display the dataset when I double click the variable explorer. The memory goes up to 80% when it runs.

I have checked that both spyder and python were updated to the latest version. Other softwares work as smoothly as before.

Does anyone know how I can get python to work normally?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Rather than try to make Spyder run faster (I can’t), I am going to advise you to at least try the excellent [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download). It’s free, even for commercial use, and every company I have contracted with in the last 8 or 9 years, has used it. For home use, I check out the opposition a few times each year, and PyCharm sill comes out tops (for me; YKmMV) ==>

Comment: ==> Take a look at Wikipedia’s [comparison of Python IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#Python); see those “no” and “partially” by Spyder? See the corresponding “yes”  by PyCharm?  Give it a try & let us know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check it out PyCharm!

Comment: It's by JetBraibns - they make the best IDEs for every language I code.